# How to avoid a ServiceStack API Explorer DTO binding error for a GET request when some of the form inputs are null

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm currently using [ServiceStack 6.10](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6_10) and in the [ServiceStack API Explorer](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer) I have the following Form for one of my services GET requests.

[image: ServiceStack API Explorer GET Request Form]

On submit a GET request is created with a querystring including null parameter values (without the equals) e.g. `?include&id&uid`. These are optional parameters so valid GET requests might be `?include&id&uid=fa70b09146431b19` or `?include&id=77&uid`.

The following `PublicationGet` DTO class fails to bind to the request. Several other requests follow the same `IUIdModel` interface and all fail to bind with the same error.

```
[Route("/publications/{Id:int}", "GET")]
[Route("/publications/{UId:string}", "GET")]
[Description("Get details of a Publication if accessible for current user session.")]
public class PublicationGet : IUIdModel, IReturn<PublicationDetails>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Id", Description = "Publication Id", DataType = "int", Route = "/publications/{Id:int}")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "UId", Description = "Publication UId", DataType = "string", Route = "/publications/{UId:string}")]
    public string UId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "Include", Description = "Comma separated list of properties on response to populate from id values.", DataType = "string", ParameterType = "body", IsRequired = false, IsOptional = true)]
    public string Include { get; set; }
}
```

When the DTO is deserialized from the request there is an extra `null` key in the `IRequest.QueryString` `NameValueCollection` which contains a comma separated list of the null parameters i.e. `id,include` and this causes an exception;

```
Unable to bind to request, SerializationException 'id,include' is an Invalid value for ''
```

This is thrown from the `StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromKeyValue` method since an inner exception is thrown by the call to `propertySetterMap.TryGetValue(propertyName, out propertySerializerEntry)` as here `propertyName` is the null key from the `NameValueCollection`.

I can't modify `IRequest.QueryString` in a pre-request filter as it's read only. I haven't found anything in the [JSON Format](https://docs.servicestack.net/json-format) configuration that might change the way the deserialization occurs.

Using the JSON view of the API Explorer works making the GET request because the parameter values for those inputs are omitted.

Removing the null parameters from the querystring will avoid the exception or making them empty instead of null (with an equals) i.e. `?include=&id=&uid=`.

Is there any way to modify the API Explorer to avoid the binding exception so the Form submit will work?

Comment: Please include the full DTO you're using and can you confirm if you're using the latest version of ServiceStack?

Comment: Thanks @mythz I'm using ServiceStack 6.10 and I've added the DTO class to the question.

Comment: Your routes are invalid, which don't support type specifiers. To support both int and string variables on the same path info you'd need to use [Custom Route Rules](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#custom-rules) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are invalid, which don't support specifying type constraints on the route, instead you would need to use [Custom Request Rules](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#custom-rules) to support multiple routes on the same variable route path, e.g:

```cs
[Route("/publications/{Id}", "GET", Matches = "**/{int}")]
[Route("/publications/{UId}", "GET")]
[Description("Get details of a Publication if accessible for current user session.")]
public class PublicationGet : IReturn<PublicationDetails>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Id", Description = "Publication Id", DataType = "int", Route = "/publications/{Id:int}")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "UId", Description = "Publication UId", DataType = "string", Route = "/publications/{UId:string}")]
    public string UId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "Include", Description = "Comma separated list of properties on response to populate from id values.", DataType = "string", ParameterType = "body", IsRequired = false, IsOptional = true)]
    public string Include { get; set; }
}
```

Also this isn't issue with the latest version of ServiceStack which doesn't send empty variables on the querystring:

[image]